# How to choose your resources dynamically based on a condition on Android?

Tags: android, localization, android-resources

In my application, I have to pick different resources based on the operator of the mobile phone (detected from the SIM) and not based on device location or language.

Is there a way on Android to tell the app dynamically if operator is X, please consider the resources from folder values-X/ ?

Answer (score 1):

According to Android doc about resource you can use **mobile country code (MCC), and mobile network code (MNC)** to achieve what you want, more about that [there](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly. You cannot invent a new `X` for use in `res/values-X/`.

Your choices are:

1. See if you can work with the MCC/MNC combination, as outlined in the table of resource set qualifiers (Table 2) in [the documentation on providing resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources).
2. Use different resource *names* by operator (e.g., `@string/something_verizon` and
   `@string/something_att` and...), using resource sets for other characteristics (e.g., natural language).

Answer (score 0):

To specify the resources to be used with particular network operator, you should know its MCC and MNC codes, and specify the resources like

```
/res/values-mcc250-mnc001/string.xml
```

(these values are for Russian "Mobile TeleSystem")

Comment: Thank you Andrey! Does it work also per MCC, MNC and language?

Comment: Sure, it works.
Please see the docs linked by other answerers.